# how to visualize a tree from datamining in Java, as a web service

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, data-mining

Hey guys I am trying to make a web service to visualize classification results of data mining. I have been able to make a web service where, when I input a training data set, I get a tree in alpha numeric form. I am using WEKA library for data mining. If I take a sample data, and plot it using the J.48 method, I get the following results:

```
N0 [label="outlook" ]
N0->N1 [label="= sunny"]
N1 [label="humidity" ]
N1->N2 [label="<= 75"]
N2 [label="yes (2.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N1->N3 [label="> 75"]
N3 [label="no (3.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N0->N4 [label="= overcast"]
N4 [label="yes (4.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N0->N5 [label="= rainy"]
N5 [label="windy" ]
N5->N6 [label="= TRUE"]
N6 [label="no (2.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N5->N7 [label="= FALSE"]
N7 [label="yes (3.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
```

Now I need to compose another webservice, where I can pass this data and get a visualization of the tree. I am really stuck here, I don't know what library to use, how to compose two webservices to work together. I am using Netbeans IDE for making the webservice. Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

When I suppose your visualization output should be something like a picture, maybe the
[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) project is a help to you.

If you are composing two webservices, you just have to call one of them by the other webservice. So your visualization service will call your raw data service and waits for the result (Or asynchronously has some callback function).
Or what is your exact problem there?

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just publish the data using JSON via HTTP?